# Loki 0.4.1 and replacing Windows help

Tags: development, microsoft-windows

I have a new Alienware 13 r3 and it came pre-loaded with Windows 10. I read that Loki 0.4.1 supports everything on this Alienware model perfectly. Touch screen included.

I'm looking to learn c# and continue writing games in c++ (cocos2d-x, qt).

What are my software options for c# on Linux? I'm looking to learn c# as most of the jobs in my area are c# and I prefer c++.

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop is a decent free program for programing in C#, F#, Visual Basic .NET, C/C++, and Vala. You can find it in the AppCentre or download it directly from their website: http://www.monodevelop.com/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is also a good option for C/C++/C#...

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

You can install the .deb package file here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Be sure to install Eddy from the App Center first to allow for the install of .deb packages.